# configuration xml file not found - spring intellij

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Trying to run a spring/tomcat server inside Intellij. Thanks for any help.

It's running fine under catalina.sh jpda start but not under intellij.

```
16:12:51.852 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:51.854 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:51.857 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:51.858 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:51.858 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:51.858 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
16:12:51.859 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
16:12:51.861 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:51.861 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:51.861 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:51.861 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:51.861 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:51.861 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
16:12:51.864 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Replacing [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with [servletContextInitParams]
16:12:51.864 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Oct 24 16:12:51 PDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
16:12:51.890 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:51.890 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:51.890 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
16:12:51.908 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:51.908 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:51.908 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
16:12:51.911 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
16:12:51.913 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class com.whoshere.em.config.service.WebSecurityConfig,class com.whoshere.em.config.service.Application]
16:12:51.936 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Bean factory for Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@68ea9a7c: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,webSecurityConfig,application]; root of factory hierarchy
16:12:51.950 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
16:12:51.951 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
16:12:51.966 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
16:12:51.967 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
16:12:52.021 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported @Configuration class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration
16:12:52.022 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.authenticationManagerBuilder()
16:12:52.022 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.enableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer()
16:12:52.022 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported @Configuration class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration
16:12:52.023 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain()
16:12:52.023 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.privilegeEvaluator()
16:12:52.024 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.webSecurityExpressionHandler()
16:12:52.024 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.autowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents()
16:12:52.024 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported @Configuration class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration
16:12:52.024 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration.objectPostProcessor()
16:12:52.025 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.whoshere.em.config.service.WebSecurityConfig.statelessSecurityContextManager()
16:12:52.025 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported @Configuration class com.whoshere.em.config.service.JdbcConfig
16:12:52.025 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.whoshere.em.config.service.JdbcConfig.jdbcTemplate()
16:12:52.026 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.whoshere.em.config.service.JdbcConfig.passwordEncoder()
16:12:52.026 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.whoshere.em.config.service.JdbcConfig./master/datasource()
16:12:52.026 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.whoshere.em.config.service.JdbcConfig._global.jdbc.txManager()
16:12:52.027 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported @Configuration class com.whoshere.em.config.service.FileStoreConfig
16:12:52.027 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.whoshere.em.config.service.FileStoreConfig.localFileStore()
16:12:52.027 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.whoshere.em.config.service.FileStoreConfig.streamingRegistry()
16:12:52.028 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.whoshere.em.config.service.FileStoreConfig.backupFileStore()
16:12:52.029 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.whoshere.em.config.service.FileStoreConfig.amazons3()
16:12:52.029 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported @Configuration class context
16:12:52.029 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported @Configuration class com.whoshere.em.context.RequestContextHolder
16:12:52.030 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported @Configuration class com.whoshere.em.context.ThreadContextHolder
16:12:52.030 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported @Configuration class com.whoshere.em.context.ThreadedScopeAdvice
16:12:52.030 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method com.whoshere.em.config.service.Application.multipartConfigElement()
16:12:52.034 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:52.034 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
16:12:52.034 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
16:12:52.037 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/em/property-configurer.xml]
16:12:52.038 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@68ea9a7c: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,webSecurityConfig,application,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration,authenticationManagerBuilder,enableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration,springSecurityFilterChain,privilegeEvaluator,webSecurityExpressionHandler,autowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents,org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration,objectPostProcessor,statelessSecurityContextManager,com.whoshere.em.config.service.JdbcConfig,jdbcTemplate,passwordEncoder,/master/datasource,_global.jdbc.txManager,com.whoshere.em.config.service.FileStoreConfig,localFileStore,streamingRegistry,backupFileStore,amazons3,context,com.whoshere.em.context.RequestContextHolder,com.whoshere.em.context.ThreadContextHolder,com.whoshere.em.context.ThreadedScopeAdvice,multipartConfigElement]; root of factory hierarchy
16:12:52.042 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
Oct 24, 2014 4:12:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/em/property-configurer.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/em/property-configurer.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
Oct 24, 2014 4:12:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:313) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:138) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:324) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4959) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1741) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:620) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:567) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1486) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:96) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1327) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1419) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:847) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_11]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/em/property-configurer.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172) ~[spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
[2014-10-24 04:12:52,563] Artifact ROOT: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

Not sure if my paths are wrong.

I also have something like this inside my Application.java.

@ImportResource( { 
    "classpath:/META-INF/fsdem/property-configurer.xml",

```
"classpath:/META-INF/em/service/txn-config.xml",
"classpath:/META-INF/em/service/redis-config.xml",
"classpath:/META-INF/em/service/ehcache-config.xml",
"classpath:/META-INF/em/service/jmx.xml",
"classpath:/META-INF/em/service/mixpanel.xml" } )
```

Answer (score 0):

In your stack trace the path is

```
[META-INF/em/property-configurer.xml]
```

But like you write later `@ImportResource( { "classpath:/META-INF/fsdem/property-configurer.xml"`

Theay are different please check path were property-configurer.xml plased